# Bind Events to Commands

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Without the use of third part DLLs, is it possible to bind the event of CellEditEnding to my command? Currently, I am using .NET 3.5, which has become an issue because it tells me that I cannot add an EventTrigger to the Trigger collection.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="EnterUserCountCommand" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but when I'm in this situation I usually just do something like this.

```
private void CellEditEndingEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    //Change params as needed
    if (viewModel.MyCommand.CanExecute(null))
        viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

Comment: I think that's the only way you can execute your command but i have one question if we use upper mention code then it's call pure mvvm?

Comment: I think this is the only way right now without manually creating a helper class to handle the bindings from the events to the commands.