# Bind a command to a specific event on an Item of ItemsControl (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, datatemplate

I would like to bind the invoke of a command when an user double clicks on an Item of my ItemsControl.

So I used System.Windows.Interactivity (v3.5):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllFiles, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FolderVM}">
            <DockPanel Margin="5" Height="70" Width="300">
                <DockPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DockPanel.Resources>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <!--Exception:Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger' to an object of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection'.-->
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="CmdBrowseFolder"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Image Height="70" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                <Grid Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Folder"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FileVM}">
            <DockPanel Margin="5" Height="70" Width="300">
                <DockPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </Style>
                </DockPanel.Resources>
                <Image Height="70" Width="70" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                <Grid Background="LightBlue" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <WrapPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SizeFormatted}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

But the following exception triggers as soon as I run the application: Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger' to an object of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection'.

Edit: Some more information:

when I comment the line with InvokeCommandAction no exception anymore. But of course the event doesn't trigger the command

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
        <!--<i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="CmdBrowseFolder"/>-->
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Another information: InvokeCommandAction in version 3.5 doesn't contain Command DP, only CommandName and CommandParameter

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's no solution for the version 3.5.

[Bind Events to Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074148/bind-events-to-commands)

I don't know why there's CommandName and CommandParameter DP if we can't use them.